# Debug hangs due to SIGINT in C++ binary using zlib

Tags: gdb, zlib

I have a working logging implementation in my code, on the top of that I have added compressed log functionality using **zlib's** gzwrite/gzflush/gzopen/gzclose functions to output the logs in compressed format.

The problem is earlier in normal logging I was able to use ctrl+c to send SIGINT and stop the program, but with compressed logs functionality enabled, **pressing ctrl+c hangs the program.**

I have tried to debug using gdb as well, when I pressed ctrl+c inside GDB, the program works as expected inside GDB, so unable to do any debug there.

**Questions**

- Is there something wrong with how I am sending SIGINT inside GDB?
- Are there any known issues with zlib, causing hangs due to SIGINT?
- Is there any other tool I can use to understand what is the source of hang in my program?

Comment: What does your SIGINT handler look like?

Comment: That's a good point, I will investigate more into it.

Comment: zlib doesn't do anything that would interfere with signals. It does not install any signal handlers.

Comment: Are you saying that if you use `fopen`, `fwrite`, `fclose`, Ctrl-C worked as you expected, but when you use `gzopen`, `gzwrite`, and `gzclose` in their place, _and change nothing else_,  then Ctrl-C does not work as you expect?

Comment: @MarkAdler Thanks for the info on signal handlers in zlib. Yes, normal file operations are working well, but gz* ones are causing hangs. Another thing I have noticed is that hangs happen only when log volume is too high.

Comment: The log volume too high may indicate a memory allocation problem. `gzopen` allocates about 256KB. If you don't  have a `gzclose` for every `gzopen`, you may run into a problem.